# How to clone specific version of TensorFlow Models + Reasearch Models

Tags: git, tensorflow

I am trying to use a specific version of [TensorFlow Models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) (1.8.0) for object detection purpose. As mentioned in that page, Research Models are not officially supported or available in release branches. So, when I use the following command to clone the git repository:

```
git clone --branch r1.8.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

After downloading about 600MB, the `Research` directory doesn’t exist in `models` directory.

How can I get `Research` directory which is compatible with r1.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout a few commits before r1.8.0:  `git checkout r1.8.0~~~`

The `models` directory was intentionally deleted. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/4752) which says "We remove research models from tagged releases, but they should remain in master indefinitely. Closing this under the assumption that it was made in error." That description doesn't tell me much. Would appreciate if anybody would explain why the tagged releases shouldn't contain research models.

Comment: It Seems It Works! Thanks